# Swift 4.1 type inference for generic array differs from Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, type-inference

Consider the code snippet below:

```
struct Foo<E> {
    var elements: [E]

    init(_ elements: [E]) {
        self.elements = elements
    }
}

var f = Foo([1.3, 4.5, 6])
print(f)
```

Notice that the array passed to the `Foo` initializer includes the integer 6.

When run under Swift 4.0, it outputs `Foo<Double>`. In Swift 4.1.2 however it outputs `Foo<Any>`. Why the difference in type inference? I can think of a few potential reasons, but I wasn't able to find documentation on the change. Can someone point to the docs?

It's worth noting that

```
var a = [1.2, 3.4, 5]
print(type(of: a))
```

produces `Array<Double>` on both 4.0 and 4.1, behaving as I'd expect.

Comment: In Xcode 10 beta 3 (Swift 4.2) it is `Foo<Double>` again, so that might be a bug in Swift 4.1.